# Spring boot rest template, distinguish local and network call

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have used REST template to call REST APIs many times.
But I was wondering, is there a way available to distinguish between local and network call.

E.g: If REST URI resolved to API call of same application then, controller/service method can be called. 
But if it is not available then network call can be made.

P.S. I know, we can do this by creating a using spring cache to list all the services of current application. 
But I was wondering if Spring REST template or any other framework provides this feature out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

*RestTemplate* doesn't support what you want to achieve OOTB.

However it sounds like you'd like to implement a RPC mechanism of some kind.

Let's say that you've got **ServiceInterface** as the service interface, **ServiceStubImpl** as the service's local stub (client) and **ServiceImpl** the concrete local implementation.

On those places where you're making calls towards **ServiceImpl** you use **ServiceInterface** obviously which actually could be the implementation itself or **ServiceStubImpl** which makes the call remotely. The latter may employ *RestTemplate* internally of other sorts of transport mechanism of your choice.

Your special use case appears to be that you don't know if **ServiceImpl** is available locally or not, but if it is, you want to call that directly instead of making network round-trips.

All of that resembles very much to Spring Boot's auto-configuration mechanisms where it seeks certain classes on the class path and performs the necessary initialization and wiring if they're available.

That said, applying Spring Boot's mechanism for your use case would look like this as an example:

```
@Configuration
class SeviceConfig {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingClass(name = "your.app.ServiceImpl")
  ServiceInterface service() {
    return new ServiceStubImpl(...);
  }

}
```

You can read more about creating your own auto-configuration with Spring Boot here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This can be done. But I am looking for a tool that would do this kind of thing internally.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, using spring cache we can do this kind of thing